# Unable to create folder on Mac (El-Capitan), permission error

Tags: macos, unix, osx-elcapitan

This simple error has me stumped:

```
(0)root@vpn-client-228# mkdir ruby-2.0.0-p645
mkdir: ruby-2.0.0-p645: Operation not permitted
(1)root@vpn-client-228# pwd
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0
(0)root@vpn-client-228#
```

Here is all the debug info I can think of:

```
(0)root@vpn-client-228# dd='/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby-2.0.0-p645'
(0)root@vpn-client-228# while [ "`dirname $dd`" != "/" ]; do dd=`dirname $dd`; ls -ld $dd; done
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  170 Dec  9 10:55 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Aug 22 19:06 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  204 Nov 24 11:19 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 Dec 14 09:52 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 Sep 17 07:27 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  204 Dec  9 10:55 /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework
drwxr-xr-x  135 root  wheel  4590 Dec  9 10:55 /System/Library/Frameworks
drwxr-xr-x  79 root  wheel  2686 Nov 24 15:40 /System/Library
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 root  wheel  136 Dec 14 09:53 /System
(0)root@vpn-client-228# 
(0)root@vpn-client-228# 
(0)root@vpn-client-228# uname -a
Darwin vpn-client-228.sv2 15.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
(0)root@vpn-client-228# 
(0)root@vpn-client-228# 
(0)root@vpn-client-228# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),1(daemon),2(kmem),3(sys),4(tty),5(operator),8(procview),9(procmod),12(everyone),20(staff),29(certusers),61(localaccounts),80(admin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
(0)root@vpn-client-228#
```

Context is I'm trying to install perftools (`sudo gem install perftools.rb -v '2.0.0'`) which fails with error `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in 'mkdir': Operation not permitted - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby-2.0.0-p645 (Errno::EPERM)'` and I'm trying to debug it.

Comment: Use `sudo` to install stuff like this, otherwise you'll run into permissions problems like the above, i.e. `sudo mkdir ruby-2.0.0-p645`, etc.

Comment: @PaulR Did that first. Didn't work. Hence logged in as `root` to be sure that sudo wasn't messing something up.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work" ? You really shouldn't need to log in as root. What are the permissions on `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0` ?

Comment: @PaulR didn't work => got same error (operation not permitted). Here some more: http://pastebin.com/hmByBGXd

Comment: Can you do an `ls -l` on that directory so that we can see what the permissions are ?

Comment: @PaulR It's already posted in the post above. Along with it's parent dirs till `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Don't Install Gems as Root

No. Just "No." Don't *ever* install gems as root. Except when you have to, really know what you're doing, and are willing to reinstall the OS when you screw something up. So just don't.

### How to Do It Right

Always use a Ruby version manager like [rvm](https://rvm.io/), [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). Even on production machines, this will save you a great deal of grief.

In particular, El Capitan has a new [System Integrity Protection (SIP)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) system that relies on special flags applied to important paths and applications. Ruby is one of those binaries:

```
$ ls -lO /usr/bin/ruby 
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted,compressed 42928 Oct 17 19:47 /usr/bin/ruby
```

and while I won't swear to it, the files or directories RubyGems is attempting to modify are probably protected, too. While you *can* bypass SIP, doing so is a Really Bad Idea™. Instead, you should use one of the version managers (both rbenv and chruby are included in [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)) to install non-system rubies and manage gems.

Comment: Thanks, that answers this question, but now that leaves me with no alternatives for my real problem. I created new post here if you could have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360947/problems-with-installation-of-perftools-gem-on-mac-el-capitan